# How to send data (a url string) in express to backend from frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build a wikipedia web scraper api and this is my code:

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti_Airlines_Flight_691"

axios.get(url).then(async (res) => {
    try {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            const result = // Doing cheerio stuff here
            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.status(200).send(result)
            })
            app.listen(port, () => {
                console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
            })
        }
    } finally {
        //
    }
});
```

How can I send `url` dynamically to backend using express and do some stuff then send `result` back to frontend?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically using express". Do you just want to wait for a response first?

Comment: @MichaelM. I want to send url dynamically to backend using express and do some stuff then send result back to frontend

Comment: The code is all messed up, the `axios.get()` must be done in the client/frontend and the `app.get()` and `app.listen()` calls must remain in the server side right below the `port` declaration, youtube basic express tutorial  will give you the answers you need.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez It's not messed up, This is just server side code and I need ```axios.get()``` to scraper data from server. ```axios.get()``` is also get used in client side to get ```res```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side:

This is a function you define in your frontend. You set a request link, which must be known here on client side and server side. Thus take something like /request. Then use axios to send a request to the server. You can pass any parameters with „dynamic“ Information as you called it. The server will receive these informations and can handle them.

```
const getData = () => {
    // insert your server url here instead, with the /request at the end
    const requestLink = `http://localhost:3001/request`;

    axios
      .get(requestLink, {
       params: { url: "wikipedia.de/test123" },
       })
      .catch((error) => {
      // here you can implement error handling
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then((res) => {
      // print result, received from the server
        console.log(res);
      });
  };
```

Server side:

The backend is going to wait for a request to the defined link /request.
If he receives such a request, he is executing the code. The req variable contains your dynamic data, such as the wiki url.

Use res.json to send data back to your frontend.

```
app.get(`/request`, (req, res) => {
     // do something with the request here
     console.log(req.query);
     // send result to the frontend
     res.json({
       status: "This could be an answer to the frontend.",
     });
    });
```

Comment: All you need is to explain the code to make this a good answer

Comment: @actioREACTio Is ```console.log(req);``` gonna print ```www.wikipedia.de/something``` ? if yes then that's all I need

Comment: @Tribe56123 yes thats exactly what happens! :)

Comment: @actioREACTio ```console.log(req)``` is not printing params also tried ```console.log(req.pramas)``` which is returning empty {}

Comment: Hello @Tribe56123, I edited my answer. Im sorry, i made a mistake before. The request link must include your server address, and please pass the params the way i did. Now it should work. You can access the params server side by printing out req.query. Please check it again, thanks.